# How do I clip a image obtained from the getImageData() function?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get the contents of a source canvas, clip it, and then draw it on another canvas. Even though my code works like a charm using a src PNG / new Image() combo, it does not when the source content comes from another canvas.

the code is:

```
var imgData = src_ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h);
dest_ctx.putImageData(imgData, x, y+h);

ctx.beginPath(); // Filled triangle
ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
ctx.lineTo(x2,0);
ctx.lineTo(x1,0);               
ctx.clip();
```

Answer (score 1):

After defining the clipping region, draw the source canvas using drawImage, instead of setting  the imagedata.

```
dest_ctx.beginPath(); // Filled triangle
dest_ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
dest_ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
dest_ctx.lineTo(x2,0);
dest_ctx.lineTo(x1,0);               
dest_ctx.clip();

// You can control wich region to draw using all the arguments
// drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
dest_ctx.drawImage (srcCanvas, x, y);
```

Comment: hi, is srcCanvas the canvas object or the canvas context?

Comment: srcCanvas is the canvas object. It works like an Image object.

Answer (score 1):

`getImageData` is an almost useless function unless you know what you're doing (ie. checking for hit detection, filtering pixels) but even then it is painfully slow.

I created a [JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/WDpfj/1/) for you fiddle around with (see what I did there!)

The heart of the code is as follows:

```
1  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
2  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
3  _canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
4  _ctx = _canvas.getContext("2d");
5  _canvas.width = 200;
6  _canvas.height = 200;
7
8  _ctx.beginPath();
9  _ctx.arc(100, 100, 100,0,Math.PI*2,true);
10 _ctx.clip();
11 _ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
12        
13 ctx.drawImage(_canvas, 1.25 * i * _canvas.width, 500);
```

Essentially what you are doing is clipping to a cache canvas (`_canvas`, lines 10 and 11) and drawing that to the main canvas (`canvas`, line 13).

Note: Ideally you would translate your image so it would be in the center of the clip, but I **still** can not get my head around translations, especially when coupled with other transformations such as clips.